# How to make an animation repeat a certain amount of times?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uiviewanimation

For some reason when I click on the button it just does nothing and the whole app shuts down. Does anyone have any suggestions? They would be much appreciated.

```
var start = 1
var timer = Timer()

func test() {
    start += 1
}

@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(TestViewController.test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    while start <= 10 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            self.buttonLabel.center = CGPoint(x:self.buttonLabel.center.x + 10, y:self.buttonLabel.center.y)
    }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your app is crashing. Provide details about the crash including the complete error message and point out the exact line causing the crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better way to repeat animations, try `UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount()`

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat], animations: {
        UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(10)
        self.buttonLabel.center = CGPoint(x:self.buttonLabel.center.x + 10, y:self.buttonLabel.center.y)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much

Comment: You are welcome. Besides, to detect reason why app is crashing (and from the question I assume your app did crashed) you can add an exception breakpoint to see what line of code caused it. To do so go to Breakpoint Navigator(left menu, top of the screen), press "+" button at the bottom of this menu and select "Exception Breakpoint". This will make debugging much easier. Cheers!

Comment: 'setAnimationRepeatCount' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the block-based animation API instead

Comment: The block-based animation API to use in this case is 
`UIView.modifyAnimations(withRepeatCount: 10, autoreverses: false) {
   self.buttonLabel.center = CGPoint(x:self.buttonLabel.center.x + 10, y:self.buttonLabel.center.y)
}
`
All inside the `animate` block.